# Contacting Microsoft with questions on Open XML

Tags: openxml, msdn

What is the best way to reach a live Microsoft developer on the phone who can answer technical questions about standardized OpenXML formats?

I have a paid MSDN support contract. I wanted to use one of my phone tickets but only production-related questions are eligible. For various reasons, I'm not interested in online support.

If this is the wrong place to ask this question, I'd appreciate a pointer in the right direction. I've been on the phone with Microsoft already and frankly I rely on StackOverflow more than Microsoft support.

Answer (score 1):

Phone support is almost always paid for. One of the only ways you're going to get free phone support is find a Microsoft-employee-friend to give you a QuickAssist card.

Other than that, forums are the way to go.

The [Office Open XML File Format Implementation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/os_openXML-ecma/threads) forum is the place to ask your questions. Forewarning though - the responses can sometimes be incredibly slow as some of the folks manning the thread are not actually experts on Open XML but instead just try to read the ECMA spec to answer your questions. If you push hard enough, you may just have some luck though. (You'll see me on there as both "*otaku*" and "*terlo*").

The other place to ask questions that is "sponsored" by Microsoft is [OpenXMLDeveloper.org](http://OpenXMLDeveloper.org). The forums you'd probably be interested in are at http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/formats/default.aspx. They don't seem to be regularly viewed by Microsoft though, but sometimes. There are other folks who try to answer questions though and do a decent job. (You'll see me on there as "*tendoors*").

Finally, Stackoverflow.com has some decent folks following [OPENXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openxml) and [OPENXML-SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openxml-sdk) tags. You can try in all 3 locations if you like :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you ask your question here, and in the Open XML Developer forum.

The msdn forums don't offer much knowledge of Open XML.

The Open XML Developer forums (http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/formats/default.aspx) employ people to answer your questions so you're somewhat guaranteed a response, however YMMV.

Here, you might just be surprised what people know.